# Weird grep corner case?

Tags: regex, linux, grep

If I have a file named 'test' with text literally:

```
\<.abc\>
```

and then run `grep -E 'abc\> | [1-5]' test`, I get no results as expected,

but when I run just `grep -E 'abc\>' test`, I get a match!

Why is this?

---

It looks like this problem was solved, but one other follow-up question:

If I wanted to use a regex like 'abc>' and for there to be no results (because no word ends with abc), how can I do this? (I also want to keep the quotes so that I can expand the regex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `grep -E 'abc\> | [1-5]' test`, I get no results as expected

because you added spaces before and after the `|`,  try:

```
 grep -E 'abc\>|[1-5]' test
```

test here:

```
kent$  grep -E 'abc\>|[1-5]' <<<'\<.abc\>'  
\<.abc\>
```

Comment: Great catch!  So if I wanted to use a regex like 'abc\>' and for there to be no results (because no word ends with abc), how can I do this?  (I also want to keep the quotes so that I can expand the regex).